# In ExactTarget-Journey Builder, is it possible to track which link is clicked by customer in an email and store it in a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

I have a requirement where in i need to store a customer click in journey builder interaction into a data extension so as to use it for next day communication based on customer interest i.e. the link clicked by him/her.

For example, a customer receives Day 0 email which has 4-5 Links for various subscriptions and services.

In the email, the customer clicks on the link that says -- "I want to renew my membership."

Can we save that click on that specific content to then tailor Day 1 communication focused on membership renewal?

Pls advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet (and simplest)would be to automate a query to the DataView _Click ([ref](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_click/)).

In this dataview you can pull the subscriber key, jobid, event date, URL, link name, etc.  You would just need to write a query to get this info and send it into a Data Extension (DE). You can then use this DE as a reference on all clicks when needed.

If you need it to be instant and into an already existing data extension, you can put a script on the page(s). You could either do an UPSERTDE ([ampscript](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/data-extension/UpsertDE.html) or [SSJS](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/data_extension_server_side_javascript_functions/)) if the page was created in SFMC, or you can add in an API call that [adds the info to your Data Extension](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/adding_data_to_data_extension_object/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. 
Can you pls advise how do i add query activity within a Journey Builder interaction that takes up the JobID of the email sent in the journey and queries _Click data view and updates the DE in real time at the time of customer click activity.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, this is a new functionality Journey Builder has now. You can do the engagement split based on a user clicking on a specific link. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

no need to store in a data extension
you can simply track the link clicked via clicks feature in engagement split and based on that give a wait event of a day and then communicate the corresponding email to the customer based upon his interests

Comment: Could you point me to reference documentation for the same, since i understand that we can only track wither email has been opened/not opened OR if links in the email have been clicked or not.

Comment: that salesforce tracks for you- links clicked by user.
i am not sure about any reference document that exists but the functionality can be very well seen in the configure option in engagement split

Answer (score 0):

As Shivam Shukla mentioned above, you create two fields for opened and clicked in your target DE. In Journey, you can have engagement to determine open or not, if opened, you just update opened = True. And the same thing for clicked. Emails must be created using the Paste HTML template type or Content Builder standard templates, custom templates, or HTML emails to support individual link tracking.